# MySQL indexing column vs multiple tables?

Tags: mysql, indexing

I have a platform where users can manage their own websites and add products. Users can't register themselves, I will add them manually.

User1 has 300,000 products,
User2 has 400,000 products,
and so on...

Should I create new "products" table for each user or indexing "user_id" will give the same performance result?

Comment: Is your current (single) table also serving as the master list of all users?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Yes, and I have to use "WHERE company_id = ?" statement in each SQL query

Comment: I would segregate and have 1 db per customer and figure out a way of upgrading each of them when required.

Answer (score 3):

If the tables can be exactly the same - **use one table**

(lets assume you'll have 1000 users - you want 1000 product tables ?)

if you'll use 1000 product tables - it also has small effect on performance, but maintanace wise - if you need to add a column - you'll have to add it 1000 times.
if you need to have site-wide statistics - you'll need to run the query 1000 times and aggregate etc....